# array alignment/sizeof() returning extra values

Tags: c, sizeof

The following bit of code...

```
void foo(char* x)
{
        int i;
        int len = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);

        printf("len: %d\n", len);
        for(i=0; i<len; i++){
                printf("i: %d, v: %x\n", i, x[i]);
        }
}
```

...when called as:

```
        char bar[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF};
        foo(bar);
```

...outputs:

```
len: 8
i: 0, v: ffffffde
i: 1, v: ffffffad
i: 2, v: ffffffbe
i: 3, v: ffffffef
i: 4, v: ffffffff
i: 5, v: 7f
i: 6, v: 0
i: 7, v: 0
```

Not exactly sure if it's applicable to this but reading through similar posts on SO, it seems to be an alignment issue (I'm on a 64 bit machine).

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing do to with alignment.

```
int len = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
```

`x` is a pointer and not an array. `sizeof (x)` computes the size of the pointer which is 8 bytes on your 64-bit machine.

Now it prints `ffffffde` insteas of `de` because of integer promotion (sign extension is performed). To avoid the `ffffff` you can use `unsigned char` type instead of `char` or cast the `printf` arguments to `unsigned int` like this:

```
printf("i: %d, v: %x\n", i, (unsigned int) x[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it's been a while since I have done C  programming hence the confusion :) So is there any way I can compute the length of the array, deferencing the pointer doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Hamza: You'll need to pass the size of the array to the function.

Comment: When you pass an entire array to a function, it decays to the pointer to the first element of the array i.e the base address of the array is passed. So you'll have to pass the size of the array to the function.